# How to fix the encode error in Django while trying to send an e-mail

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Im trying to send an verification e-mail to a new registrated account  in Django, but im getting an encode error that I dont know how to fix, please help me to fix it, so then I can succeffuly verify the account

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

```
if DEBUG:
        EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        EMAIL_PORT = 587
        EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
        EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'jamelaumn@gmail.com'
        EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = xxxxx  # important
    else:
        EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

my urls.py:

```
path('register/', views.account_register, name='register'),
```

my views.py:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode, urlsafe_base64_encode
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def account_register(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('account:dashboard')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
            user = registerForm.save(commit=False)
            user.email = registerForm.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(registerForm.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.is_active = False
            email_to = user.email
            user.save()
            email_subject = 'Ative sua conta'
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            message = render_to_string('account/registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })

            email_body = message

            email = EmailMessage(
                email_subject,
                email_body,
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email_to])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('registered succesfully and activation sent')
    else:
        registerForm = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/registration/register.html', {'form': registerForm})


def account_activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
        user = UserBase.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, user.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('account:dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account/registration/activation_invalid.html')
```

Error in console

```
C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 652, in auth authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='') AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' [25/May/2022 16:49:50] "POST /django-store-account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 92726
```

Entire console  error encode:

```
Internal Server Error: /django-store-account/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", 
line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\account\views.py", line 134, in account_register      
    email.send()
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 91, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 652, in auth
    authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
[25/May/2022 21:24:58] "POST /django-store-account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 92687
```

with send_mail:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error is being thrown by the built-in smtp python library it means that you're passing the wrong kind of encoding. According to the docs, and the error message, it expects binary but will try to convert to ASCII if it receives a string.

It seems that somewhere you're passing an int , but instead of chasing down the encodings, since you're not using any of the advanced features of `EmailMessage` you should be able to just use the utility method provided by Django [send_email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#send-mail)

So, this should do it

```py
    mail.send_mail(subject = email_subject, message = message, 
                   from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email_to], 
                   html_message=html_message)
```

There should be no need for an encoding, you can just use the context values in your template as usual, then generate the *text/plain* message by striping the HTML with [strip_tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.strip_tags) , i.e. `message = strip_tags(html_message)`

Comment: sorry did'nt understand the last part about the encode, "strip tags"

Comment: also I tried your code, got an sintax error

Comment: Insted of [email_to] at final I put at the beggining, but when I checked my e-mail it wasnt sent

Comment: Read the docs I linked to. The named argument for the recipients is `recipient_list`

Comment: okay I used the scripts tags to send this: html_message = "<br> aaa </br>" the views is working fine, but the e-mail is not being sent, could you help? I dont get any error in console

Comment: The strip tags method allows you to remove html tags from your html string. So you can pass that  in the “message” argument as a backup, so that if html is not supported by the recipient’s email client, they can see the text of the message but without formatting

Comment: oh understood, but do you know if I do some other configuration? the view is working without error, but when I check e-mail in gmail I didn't send anything

Comment: Probably a wrong config. To debug I would recommend testing it separately. Just run an interactive shell and try sending an email by calling send_mail. If you’re still having problems, ask a separate question though ‘cause it would be unrelated to your original encoding error, which is now solved

Comment: There are already several questions on SO about configuring gmail properly. I would recommend checking that you’ve tried those before asking a new question. Good luck